# XML DocumentWriter - Stop empty elements appearing over two lines in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I am using the XML document object in VB.NET to manipulate XML.

My application creates a new XML fragment and updates the XML via the innerXML method:

reasonFrag.InnerXml = String.Format("`<ReasonForPayment>`{0}`</ReasonForPayment>`", reason)

This produces the correct XML output on most occasions, e.g.
`<ReasonForPayment>`reason`</ReasonForPayment>`

If the reason string is empty I get element spanning two lines in the XML as follows:

`<ReasonForPayment>`
`</ReasonForPayment>`

I am looking for a way of keeping the element on a single line while maintaining the same format, e.g.

`<ReasonForPayment></ReasonForPayment>`

The alternative `<ReasonForPayment />` is not acceptable (third party application wont accept it).

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to handle this would be to do something like this:

```
if (reason == null | reason.Trim() == "")
{
  reasonFrag.IsEmpty = true;
}
else
{
  reasonFrag.InnerText = reason.Trim();
}
```

This changes the output to

```
<ReasonForPayment/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(reason))
{
   reasonFrag.InnerXml = "<ReasonForPayment></ReasonForPayment>"
}
else
{
   reasonFrag.InnerXml = String.Format("<ReasonForPayment>{0}</ReasonForPayment>", reason)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned I tried that, but the result still spans two lines.

Comment: So mayby try to replace "<ReasonForPayment>\n\r</ReasonForPayment>" with "<ReasonForPayment></ReasonForPayment>" in your final XML, or use TextWriter instead of XmlDocument.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but I was hoping for something simple like setting a XML document setting.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but maybe something like

*edit* threw it into LinqPad, works just fine for what you need.

```
public static string ToXmlFragment(this object input, string element)
{
    //extension method, place in a static class somewhere
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.ToString()) ? 
        string.Format("<{0}></{0}>",element) :
        string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>",element,input);
}


reasonFrag.InnerXml = reason.ToXmlFragment("ReasonForPayment");
```

Comment: I agree, your code should* work, but the XMLDocument object is adding in the newline when I call the Save routine. I was hoping there was a XMLSetting or property I could set to prevent this.

Comment: Really... that's a little odd. I'll look into it further.

Comment: Can you post your full serialize method?

Comment: Public Sub sample()
        Dim myXMLDoc As New XmlDocument
        Dim myFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = myXMLDoc.CreateDocumentFragment()
        myFrag.InnerXml = "<ReasonForPayment></ReasonForPayment>"
        Dim DocRoot As XmlElement = myXMLDoc.CreateElement("Root")
        myXMLDoc.AppendChild(DocRoot)
        DocRoot.AppendChild(myFrag)
        myXMLDoc.Save("c:\temp\out.xml")
    End Sub

Comment: The above reproduces the problem

Comment: That's interesting. I have no idea why it's doing that or any easy way to stop it. My first thought as a workaround save it to a string buffer, and then run through and strip any ">\n\r</" into "></"

Comment: Just to add to the mystery, if I replace a empty strings with #REPLACE# I get the following in the XML document...

Comment: <ReasonForPayment>#REPLACE#</ReasonForPayment>

Comment: If I then use the following routine to replace this text 
    Private Sub ReplaceStringInFile(ByVal dest As String)
        Dim xml As String = File.ReadAllText(dest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        xml = xml.Replace("#REPLACE#", String.Empty)
        File.WriteAllText(dest, xml, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    End Sub  I still get the additional CRLF in my output.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was unusual. When reading or writing files in .NET using streamreader/writer, textreader/writer and the XMLDocument object, the document format changes depending on the file extension. So for example reading a file with a XML extension, the file is treated and formatted as XML. This was causing my original problem, a empty element was output over two lines with a CRLF inserted. The solution was to output the steam to a file with a .txt extension and then rename the file to XML, then my formatting was preserved.